# upload binary image in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]await fetch("https://******?filename=amit.png", {
            method: "POST",
            params: {filename : "amit.png"},
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Basic *****",
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
            },
            body: feedbackData.photo.base64
        })

in body  i am passing base64 , the image which is showing on server is empty.
i am missing some thing in body. please help.

Comment: Rather than sending the file as boday send it as a formdata. 
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', {
        uri: uriOfTheFile,
        type: 'image/jpeg/jpg',
        name: nameOfTheFile,
        data: theFile,
      });
await fetch("https://******?filename=amit.png", { method: "POST", params: {filename : "amit.png"}, headers: { Authorization: "Basic *****", "Content-Type": "imultipart/form-data" }, body: formData })

For reference and example follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518315/10398005. I hope you get some Idea what exactly to do.

Comment: Hi @PratapSharma thanks for the help but zendesk api not supporting to fromdata, its only supporting binary. could you help me to convert in binary. i tried few library but not supporting with expo